# PHP compare two objects with same properties but different properties values, get non-matching values

Tags: php, object, comparison

I have these two objects contained in a array:

```
array (size=2)
 0 => 
object(stdClass)[20]
  public 'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
  public 'surname' => string 'D' (length=1)
  public 'id_number' => string '924' (length=3)
  public 'file' => string '1001' (length=4)
  public 'arrival_date' => string '1368466111' (length=10)
1 => 
object(stdClass)[21]
  public 'name' => string 'John' (length=4)
  public 'surname' => string 'D' (length=1)
  public 'id_number' => string '924' (length=3)
  public 'file' => string '1002' (length=4)
  public 'arrival_date' => string '1368466190' (length=10)
```

It would be great to come up with 3 arrays or 3 objects like the following:

```
array('name'=>'John','surname'=>'D','id_number'=>'924') - contains the matching values
array('file'=>'1001','arrival_date'=>'1368466111') - contains the first set of different values
array('file'=>'1002','arrival_date'=>'1368466190') - 2nd set of not matching values
```

The story behind the code is that upon the arrival of each person, I open a file, and at some point in time, I want each person to list his name and beneath his name and identification (that are identical for each arrival) to list his arrival files, each in a row.

What do you, think? Is there any neat way to accomplish this? What I did so far is a mess - tons of code with poor results.

Comment: No code is poor code until you have untested it and launched it at production time. Let's see what you've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are built in functions for that. You do need to cast the objects to an array for this to work though (which is an array of all public properties of the object). Assuming your variable is called `$var`:

```
$a1 = (array)$var[0];
$a2 = (array)$var[1];
$inBoth       = array_intersect_assoc($a1, $a2);
$onlyInFirst  = array_diff_assoc($a1, $a2);
$onlyInSecond = array_diff_assoc($a2, $a1);
```

Comment: this won't work for properties that are not castable to string, unfortunatly.

Comment: @Florian indeed it won't, nice catch. In those cases you would have to make the comparison more elaborate, and create a string for those variables that can't be casted manually, or somehow compare the fields manually.

Comment: yeah , the only solution I found is a good old loop and identity comparison, collecting those who differ :/

Comment: For short, `(array) $classA == (array) $classB`